# Why should people give their social media info to the US govt?

Tags: usa, visas

US has recently decided to vet visa-seekers by using their provided social media info.

Why should people give their social media info to the US govt?

Suppose, someone has 10 social media accounts, and all of them are clean, but he only gives one.

What can the US government do?

Comment: Refuse to grant visa?......

Comment: Same thing as when INS used to ask if you were or have ever been a member of Communist Party

Comment: Why wouldn't you just say you don't have any?

Comment: Travel.se handles a lot these sorts of question, security.se handles some "how much could x know?" questions. In my opinion this seems aimed away from the politics of the situation.

Comment: @notstoreboughtdirt - I flagged it for a mod and mentioned that it should be on travel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an older question, but as this seems to have come into effect last night it's probably worthy of an update.

When filling in the DS-160 form to apply for a US non-immigrant visa the following question is now included :

[image: Social Media question]

The list of available Social Media platforms is :

[image]

As to whether you should provide this information and what happens if you don't, the simple fact is that by not providing this information would be you entering false details on a visa application, which could very likely be treated as making a fraudulent application.  That could have consequences up to and including your visa not being issued, or being revoked at a later stage.  Obviously how likely this is to occur is unknown as this stage.

As with all questions on a visa application the best advice would be to answer it honestly - although even then there's signifciant grey area here as far as what constitutes a "social media account" (eg, I have a Google account, and I used YouTube - but does that mean I need to list YouTube even though I've never posted any videos on it?)

Note that this is unrelated to the similar question on the ESTA application which is optional so can be skipped.

Comment: Yeah, this is extremely murky -- what if I have a private Twitter account? What if I have a Facebook account but never post in public (many do so).

Comment: No 'other' option... I'd be interested to hear how this gets used in the future.

Comment: @chx I don't see what's murky. If you have a Twitter/FB/whatever account, you give it, period. It does not matter whether it's private or how often, if at all, you use it.

Comment: @fkraiem What if you don't remember the username?  I have a Google account, which means I also have a YouTube account - do I need to list it even though I've never uploaded/etc anything on YouTube?  Same for Google+ (although it no longer exists, but same point).  Definitely murky...

Comment: @Doc Not more murky that other things you might not remember, such as past travels. As for your YouTube account, it seems obvious to me that if you have visited YouTube while logged into it, this should count has having used it.

Comment: I don't know whether to be happy or disappointed that Stack Exchange is not an option.

Answer (score 6):

US can revoke the visa for lying at any future time.  If it's any kind of work-permit or residency visa, then that can put you at the mercy of anyone who knows about such an account and may want to blackmail you in the future.